Why is Bitbucket pipeline throwing 'authorization denied by plugin pipelines' error for AWS Lambda function invocation?
I have a Bitbucket pipeline running integration tests. For the pipeline I built an image upon python:3.11-alpine using aws-sam-cli==1.115.0. I pushed the built image to a doctl registry, then I reference the image in my pipelines yaml configuration file.
image:
  name: registry.digitalocean.com/myuri

After this I built my template, then ran sam local start-api with correct parameters. Then I run a bash script which seeds the database, then in a node environment I run exported Postman collections with newman.
Node: 21.7.2
Newman: 5.2.0
What is strange to me is that the first few Lambda invocations are successful, then after a few requests I get the following exception:
samcli.commands.local.cli_common.user_exceptions.DockerDistributionAPIError: 403 Client Error for http://localhost:2375/v1.35/distribution/public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11-x86_64/json: Forbidden ("authorization denied by plugin pipelines: ")

I'm upgrading from python3.9 and along with it I also need to update my lambda layers. So I updated from psycopg2.5 to 2.9.9. I don't think that should have an affect on this problem tho. Reverting my changes and using my earlier - python3.9 - image solves the pipeline issue.
I tried running the test locally and everything works fine there too.

It is hard to tell exactly unless you share the scripts being run in the pipeline, but my bet is you are trying to do some docker operation that is forbidden. Bitbucket Pipelines' Docker execution environment is severely constrained. E.g. using extra container capabilities or trying to mount a path outside the default workdir will not work.

These Lambda functions run inside containers. So that has to do something with it. Still it's very strange that I can invoke them a few times before getting this error. You are probably right about the Bitbukcet Docker execution environment.

I still couldn't solve this issue., although I got a log from the pipelines docker daemon, which I think is responsible for the issue: level=error msg="AuthZRequest for GET /v1.35/distribution/public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11-x86_64/json returned error: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: "
Still I have no solution for it

Turns out SAM was making request to pull the latest Lambda images from ecr. I guess there is some sort of rate limiting mechanism in Bitbucket pipelines causing only the first few pulls to succeed from ecr. I solved the issue by starting SAM with --skip-pull-image option.
